# How can I add a try and catch in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a Webview in Java. Being a newview wondering how can I add a try and catch here? Please help me

```
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.gymnasiumebingen.de");
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

 myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
     public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
         startActivity(i);
      }
  });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }
```

Comment: `try { /* code to be watched */ } catch (ExceptionToCatch e) { /* code after exception happened */ }`

Comment: @FurkanTekno , this part of the code is not enough, please, provide the full code of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed () {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            try {
                // protect code that may fail
                myWebView.goBack();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                // write some code to mitigate
                // the failure
            } 
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

You can do that around any piece if code that might throw an exception. This catches all possible exceptions but you can even catch targeted ones.

Bear in mind that it will not protect the listener code if you surround the declaration. You need to put a try catch around the listener code